# program does not contain a static main method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

I try to call main function with parameter. but i cannot call this function. also i got these error. is it possible to call main function with parameter?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(long Price)
    {   
        Amount = Price;
        Console.WriteLine(Amount);
    }

    void Go()
    {
        Main(34);
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you have several questions. 1 To run the program you need entry point, which is public status void main. 2 main could  have parameters. Is it what you asking ?

Comment: Change the argument type from `long` to `string[]`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/

Answer (score 1):

use `Main(string[] args)` instead:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long Price = long.Parse(args[0]);
        Go( Price );
    }

    static void Go(long Price)
    {
        var Amount = Price;
        Console.WriteLine(Amount);
    }       
}
```